# How to list a source file's "structure" (e.g. list all the methods) with eglot/lsp?

Tags: lsp-mode, lsp, eglot

There is a similar question here: https://superuser.com/questions/629090/emacs-displaying-list-of-subroutines-functions-classes-in-a-source-file

But it was from 2013, way before LSP and eglot became things. Since LSP already knows which symbols are method names (afaik), I suppose there is a more accurate command than `occur` to list all the methods, all the properties, etc?

This is the corresponding feature in Rider:

[image]

Of course I don't need those cute icons in emacs, but the image shows, Rider knows which symbols are private fields, method names, etc.

Comment: The linked thread has an answer suggesting [Imenu](https://superuser.com/a/1330598/568188). (`M-g i` in Emacs 29). Built-in UI is kinda succinct but reincarnations may work quite fine: [EmacsWiki: Imenu Mode](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ImenuMode), [imenu-list](https://github.com/bmag/imenu-list)

Comment: @Y.E. How could I just jump to an item on the top-level with `imenu` tho? It keeps asking me to input a name recursively until I reach to the inner-most block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emacs has a built–in feature called Imenu that lets you easily jump to any definition in the current file (or project) by name. Any major mode can populate this menu, and therefore most do. Type `M-g i` (or run `M-x imenu`) to open a prompt asking you where you want to go. See [chapter 27.2.4 Imenu](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Imenu.html) of the Emacs manual for more information.

If you want a *visible* list of definitions, there are several options. You can add imenu to your menu bar, if you use the menu bar (see the documentation for details on how to do that). You can install any of several packages such as [`imenu-list`](https://github.com/bmag/imenu-list) or [`popup-imenu`](https://github.com/ancane/popup-imenu) that give you different ways of seeing the list of definitions.

The `lsp-ui` package can also add a [visible list of definitions](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-ui#lsp-ui-imenu), but I think it only works with `lsp-mode` not `eglot`. It might be made to work though, since ultimately it just gets the info from imenu. I leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: I tried 'imenu', but it's such a werid command. It asks me to input the name of the method, and after I press RET it asks the name of a variable, then the name of a variable nested in it, then the name of a variable nested it...
Can I just jump to the top-level method without jumping hoops?

Comment: It depends quite a lot on how the mode you are using puts data into the index, but I think you can leave the prompt blank at any point to stop at that level.

Comment: Oh I know where the problem was... some package (`corfu` maybe? Haven't pinpointed it) atuo-fill the blank prompt with the symbol under the cursor. So it just jumps to the symbol under the cursor, i.e. not jumping at all